# Where is my PHP/MySQL syntax error?

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I may have just been looking at this for too long, but I fail to see the error. Any help would be appreciated.

The error:

> Error occurred in [INSERT INTO 'PlayerSats'
>   (username,character,FirstPlay) VALUES ('WaxyChicken','20','FALS')]:
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''PlayerSats' (username,character,FirstPlay) VALUES
>   ('WaxyChicken','20','FALS')' at line 1

Do note that "PlayerSats" is not a typo and is properly capitalized.

The Code:

```
if ($Funct == "SETFIRSTPLAY") {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $PlayerStats (username,character,FirstPlay) VALUES ('$username','$Char','FALS')";
    mysql_query($sql) or die("Error occurred in [$sql]: " . mysql_error());
    echo "SUCCESS";
}
```

The table structure:

```
CREATE table PlayerStats (
    ID int(10) unsigned not null auto_increment,
    username char(20) not null default '' utf8_general_ci,
    character char(2) not null default '00' utf8_general_ci,
    invLand char(115) not null default '000:99' utf8_general_ci,
    FirstPlay char(4) not null default 'true' utf8_general_ci,
    Bank int(20) unsigned not null default 2000
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column "character" is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL... you either need to escape by enclosing it in back-ticks or use another column name

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $PlayerStats (username,`character`,FirstPlay) VALUES ('$username','$Char','FALS')";
```

Comment: dropped Character and made chrtr with same attributes.  tried the same command: Error occurred in [INSERT INTO 'PlayerSats' (username, chrtr,FirstPlay) VALUES ('WaxyChicken','21','FALS')]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''PlayerSats' (username, chrtr,FirstPlay) VALUES ('WaxyChicken','21','FALS')' at line 1

Comment: don't use the single quote around your table name... either use the backtick ` or use nothing at all

Comment: CORRECT. i had forgotten to also remove the single quotes from INSERT INTO '$PlayerStats'. error fixed. Thank you everyone. $sql = "INSERT INTO $PlayerStats (username, chrtr,FirstPlay) VALUES ('$username','$Char','FALS')";

Answer (score 2):

You have a `$` in front of PlayerStats. Try:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO PlayerStats (username,character,FirstPlay) VALUES ('$username','$Char','FALS')";
```

Comment: $PlayerStats = phpvarable containing "PlayerSats" (notice the spelling)

Comment: Then add single quotes around it as such `'$PlayerStats'`

Comment: $PlayerStats = 'PlayerSats'; with $sql = "INSERT INTO '$PlayerStats' (username, .... is the same error.  as is $PlayerStats = 'PlayerSats'; with $sql = "INSERT INTO $PlayerStats (username, ....

Comment: notice it does not say "cannot find table"

Answer (score 1):

Table names does not to be encclosed in quotes. Should be just

```
INSERT INTO PlayerSats (username,character,FirstPlay) VALUES ('WaxyChicken','20','FALS')
```

Comment: they should be quoted if they're reserved words, but then you use backticks anyways.

Comment: No good  '  Error occurred in [INSERT INTO PlayerSats (username,character,FirstPlay) VALUES ('WaxyChicken','20','FALS')]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'character,FirstPlay) VALUES ('WaxyChicken','20','FALS')' at line 1'